# and multiple selectedObjects in NSArrayController

Tags: objective-c, nstableview, nsarraycontroller

When ever there is more than one object selected in my TableView,  [NSTableView clickedColumn] always returns a negative (non-valid) int. Is there a way to get the clickedColumn for this situation?

Comment: That is because nothing is clicked when multiple rows are selected